# SQL Query -- Select InnerJoin

Tags: sql

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction. I cant get this query to work. Basically, i have two tables 'Country' and 'Streams'. 'Country' contains a primary key column (i.e., id) and a 'CountryName' column (you can guess what it contains). The 'Streams' table contains a primary key column, a 'Status' column and a 'Country_ID' column.

I would like to SELECT all items in the Country.CountryName column WHERE the corresponding Streams.Country_ID equals 'Online'. I know i need to create an inner join to pull this off... but i just cant get the syntax to work.

```
SELECT CountryName FROM Country WHERE Streams.Status = 'Online' INNER JOIN Streams ON Streams.Country_ID = Country.CountyID;
```

As always... any and all help appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your inner join needs to come before the where

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN` is not a clause.  It is a keyword that belongs in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks all -- greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW -- I really dont get when people mark you down... i asked because i'm trying to learn. If you dont want to help... dont -- simples! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CountryName FROM Country 
  INNER JOIN Streams ON Streams.Country_ID = Country.ID
     WHERE Streams.Status = 'Online';
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CountryName FROM Country C INNER JOIN Streams S ON S.Country_ID = C.CountyID WHERE S.Status = 'Online';

Comment: Hi Nitesh -- i'm curious as to why your query is different to Derek's and Bhaumik's? Therefore the 'C' before 'INNER JOIN' and 'S' before 'ON', for example.

Comment: C and S are called Table Aliases that you can use as a short form name to use in other places in the query.  NOTE:  you should also be able to remove C and S, and C. and S. everywhere since your column names are unique.

Comment: SELECT CountryName FROM Country INNER JOIN Streams ON Country_ID = CountyID WHERE Status = 'Online';

Comment: Yes, Derek is right. I have used aliases for tables which let you use short name for tables in query.

Answer (score 1):

Give this Query a Shot.

```
SELECT CountryName FROM Country INNER JOIN Streams ON Streams.Country_ID = Country.CountyID WHERE Streams.Status = 'Online' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Derek/Nitesh, you were close. I had to change your queries slightly. Many thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountryName FROM Country INNER JOIN Streams ON Country_ID = Country.id WHERE Streams.Status = 'Online'
```